# javascript recursion creating n-level for-loops

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to solve [this xkcd problem](http://xkcd.com/287/) using javascript.
(For those who don't like to click links, here it is:
Find all the combinations of on the menu totaling $15.05, given a list of:

1. mixed fruit, $2.15
2. french fries, $2.75
3. salad, $3.35
4. hot wings, $3.55
5. mozzarella sticks, $4.20
6. sampler platter, $5.80

I solved it using a brute force method- it's ugly and messy and not flexible, but I know my solution is (7 mixed fruit) and (2 hot wings, 1 mixed fruit, 1 sampler plate).

I **want** to solve it using recursion, because (in this imaginary restaurant) what if the number of menu changes someday?  Or the price does?  It's pretty common for menu items and prices to change, and I'd like my solution to work **all the time**.

could anyone point me in the right direction? I'm stuck here:

```
var itemArray =  [
            {
                "desc": "mixed fruit",
                "val": 2.15,
                "maxQuantity": 7
            },
            {
                "desc": "french fries",
                "val": 2.75,
                "maxQuantity": 5
            },
            {
                "desc": "salad",
                "val": 3.35,
                "maxQuantity": 4
            },
            {
                "desc": "hot wings",
                "val": 3.55,
                "maxQuantity": 4
            },
            {
                "desc": "mozzarella sticks",
                "val": 4.20,
                "maxQuantity": 4
            },
            {
                "desc": "sampler platter",
                "val": 5.80,
                "maxQuantity": 3
            }
        ];
     /*maxQuantity is (15.05/val), rounded up to nearest integer, and represents 
        the maximum number of a single menu item before reaching 15.05 */
    function doLoops (menuItemsJSON, index){        
         var sum= 0, lines = 0;
         debugger;
        if(index < 0){
            return;
        }
        else{


                for(var a = 0; a < menuItemsJSON[index].maxQuantity; a++ ){
                    sum += parseFloat(menuItemsJSON[index].val);

                    lines++;

                    console.log(" lines: " + lines + " index: " + index+ " maxQ: "+ (menuItemsJSON[index].maxQuantity) +" a: "+ a +  ", sum: " + sum.toFixed(2));

                }//end for
                doLoops(menuItemsJSON, index - 1);
            }//end else
            return;

    }
    doLoops(itemArray, (itemArray.length - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned on the comic, this problem problem is the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete). This implies that all possible algorithms solving the problem are bruteforce (or similar to bruteforce). Unless [P=NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), which is very unlikely.

So, what you could do would be:

```
function doLoops(menuItemsJSON, index, targetPrice) {
    if (index < 0)
        return (targetPrice == 0)
    else {
        for(var a = 0; a < menuItemsJSON[index].maxQuantity; a++ ){
            targetPrice -= parseFloat(menuItemsJSON[index].val);
            if (doLoops(menuItemsJSON, index - 1, targetPrice)) { // Recursive call to look for a solution with 'a' instances of this appetizer
                // We reached a solution
                console.log(menuItemsJSON[index].desc + ": " + a);
                return true;
            }
            // No solution, let's try another one
        }
        return false; // No solution at all
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram MathWorld summarizes the [Knapsack Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnapsackProblem.html) really well:

> Given a [sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sum.html) and a set of [weights](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Weight.html), find the [weights](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Weight.html) which were used to generate the [sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sum.html).

[image: NP-Complete]

In our case the sum is `15.05` and the weights are as follows:

```
var weights = [{
    name: "Mixed Fruit",
    cost: 2.15
}, {
    name: "French Fries",
    cost: 2.75
}, {
    name: "Side Salad",
    cost: 3.35
}, {
    name: "Hot Wings",
    cost: 3.55
}, {
    name: "Mozzarella Sticks",
    cost: 4.20
}, {
    name: "Sampler Plate",
    cost: 5.80
}];
```

The general way of solving the knapsack problem is recursive:

```
function solve(result, sum, weights) {
    var length = weights.length;
    var index  = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        var weight = weights[index++];
        var cost   = weight.cost;

        if (cost > sum) continue;

        var newResult = result.concat(weight);

        if (cost === sum) return newResult;

        newResult = solve(newResult, sum - cost, weights);

        if (newResult.length > 0) return newResult;
    }

    return [];
}
```

It works as follows:

1. Initially, `result` is an empty array.
2. For each `weight`:

   1. If it's `cost` is greater than the `sum` then skip it.
   2. If it's `cost` is equal to the `sum` then stop. You have found a solution. Add the `weight` to the `result` and return it.
   3. Otherwise the `cost` is less than the `sum`. Add the `weight` to the `result`, subtract the `cost` from the `sum` and call `solve` recursively.
3. If you didn't find any solution then return an empty array which denotes that no solution was found.

It should be noted that because the knapsack problem is NP-complete we can only find a solution to the problem using brute force ([currently](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PVersusNPProblem.html)). This is exactly what we are doing when we call `solve([], 15.05, weights)`:

```js
var sum = 15.05;

var weights = [{
    name: "Mixed Fruit",
    cost: 2.15
}, {
    name: "French Fries",
    cost: 2.75
}, {
    name: "Side Salad",
    cost: 3.35
}, {
    name: "Hot Wings",
    cost: 3.55
}, {
    name: "Mozzarella Sticks",
    cost: 4.20
}, {
    name: "Sampler Plate",
    cost: 5.80
}];

alert(JSON.stringify(solve([], sum, weights), null, 4));

function solve(result, sum, weights) {
    var length = weights.length;
    var index  = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        var weight = weights[index++];
        var cost   = weight.cost;

        if (cost > sum) continue;

        var newResult = result.concat(weight);

        if (cost === sum) return newResult;

        newResult = solve(newResult, sum - cost, weights);

        if (newResult.length > 0) return newResult;
    }

    return [];
}
```

If you run the above code then you will see that the solution to this particular problem is:

```
[{
    name: "Hot Wings",
    cost: 3.55
}, {
    name: "Mixed Fruit",
    cost: 2.15
}, {
    name: "Hot Wings",
    cost: 3.55
}, {
    name: "Sampler Plate",
    cost: 5.80,
}];
```

Hence, [Cueball](http://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Cueball) orders two hot wings, one mixed fruit and one sampler plate.

Answer (score 0):

For recursion problems, I like to start with the base case(s) first. I'd suggest writing the method to take a `targetAmount` argument (and possibly a reference to the menu, if that won't be stored somewhere globally accessible). The base cases are a) if the target amount is 0, return true, and b) if the target amount is negative, return false. Those are the situations for success and failure on the recursion.

From there, the only other possibility is that the target amount is positive. In this case, the method should iterate through the menu items and try each one. It should subtract the value of the item from the target amount to get a new target, and make a recursive call with that new target. If that recursive call is false, move along to the next item - there was no success finding any combination of items to reach the new target amount after choosing this item. If that recursive call is true, this was the last item chosen (it reduced the target amount to 0), so bundle the item into an array and return it. If that recursive call returns an array, it succeeded somewhere on this path, so unshift the selected item into the front of the array and return that new array.

In code, that method might look like this

```
function knapsack (targetAmount) {
  if (targetAmount === 0) {
    return true; // base case for success
  }
  if (targetAmount < 0) {
    return false; // base case for failure
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++ ) {
    var item = itemArray[i];
    var itemPrice = item.val;
    var newTargetAmount = targetAmount - itemPrice;
    var outcome = knapsack(newTargetAmount);
    if (outcome === false) {
      continue; // this item failed, try the next
    } else if (outcome === true) {
      // for the target amount requested this item is the entire selection
      return [item.desc]; 
    } else { // received a list of items, prepend the chosen item and return
      outcome.unshift(item.desc);
      return outcome;
    }
  }

  return false; // if nothing worked for this targetAmount, fail.
}
```

If you want to get every possible combination for a target amount, rather than just the first one encountered, it will be a bit more complex. The base cases are the same, but when iterating through the items, the method can never return early - it needs to check every item in the list, every time. In this case, the method can collect all solutions and return this collection. This means that rather than getting just an array returned for a solution, the method will be returning an collection of arrays (probably represented as an array of arrays). Each inner array is a possible solution, and during the recursion the method should prepend the selected item to each inner array and dump those new arrays in its own collection of solutions. After iterating through all the items, the method can return its new collection of solutions, which might be an empty collection.

Comment: Thank you- this was a pretty clear example (that reminds me that I need to think about using array methods like unshift better!) which also gives me the steps to get all possible combinations.  Like I mentioned, I brute forced it with my first try, so I know that there are two answers and I'd like my recursion method to account for that as well.

Comment: That's definitely doable, though it will slow down very quickly as the number of items grows. You can get there by setting up the return collection `var solutions = []` before the for loop, and returning that collection instead of `false` at the end. Then, you'll need to change the `outcome === true` and `else` conditions. The former should insert the single item array it's currently returning into the solutions collection. The latter will receive an array of arrays - it needs to unshift the selected item into each inner array (if there are any) and add each to the solutions array. Good luck!